# nodejs understanding event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found the following code in a tutorial and I'm trying to understand how the call stack and event loop work:

```
// Async task (same in all examples in this chapter)
function async(arg, callback) {
  console.log('do something with \''+arg+'\', return 1 sec later');
  setTimeout(function() { callback(arg * 2); }, 1000);
}
// Final task (same in all the examples)
function final() { console.log('Done', results); }

// A simple async series:
var items = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
var results = [];
function series(item) {
  if(item) {
    async( item, function(result) {
      results.push(result);
      return series(items.shift());
    });
  } else {
    return final();
  }
}
series(items.shift());
```

I drew a picture to help myself visualize but I think I can explain better than I drew it out:

[image]

From my understanding, the first and only function added to the call stack is series(1) whose callback is added to the poll phase since it's asynchronous? Because there's nothing on the call stack after series(1) is invoked, the following is run immediately:

```
console.log('do something with \''+arg+'\', return 1 sec later');
```

and not after one second (but just for series(1)). Then, the timeout is invoked, and I'm assuming the event loop is idle at this point because the call stack is completely empty.

The timer finishes, pushes the callback to the call stack, runs the synchronous code and the process continues for the rest of the functions until final is run.

I think this is how it works, but I'm confused on how many cycles this would take. Is this all happening in one loop? because series(1) calls series(2) and so the event loop never leaves the poll phase? or does it continue looping and checking the call stack until it finds that the timer finished?

I'm just trying to get a solid understanding if someone would care to clarify

Comment: Not sure about the "Poll Phase" - never heard/read anything about a "Poll Phase" in Javascript event loop - is that a V8 thing? There's some great videos about the event loop you can search for on youtube - also this `return 1 sec later` is misleading, since `function async` *returns* immediately after setTimeout is started

Comment: First off, no function should be named `async`.  That's just downright misleading, allowed (probably for backward compatibility reasons) but misleading.

Comment: Nothing complicated going on here.  Just `setTimeout()` being used to call the same function over and over again until the array is depleted.  This is a more complicated way to write something than it needs to be.  Really nothing complicated at all related to the event loop.  It's just `setTimeout()`, that's all.  There is no poll phase activity here at all.  Read about how timers work in nodejs if you want more detail.

Comment: Try putting a `console.log("end of code here")`  after your call to `series(items.shift())` at the end of your code.  You will see that the first `series()` executes, sets a timer and returns and the call stack completely unwinds.  Then, the timer fires and `series(...)` gets called again.  That process repeats until there are no more items when everything is done.

Comment: @JaromandaX poll phase is directly from nodejs documentation. I'm confused what you mean by returning immediately after setTimeout is started. Isn't the function only returned when the callback is invoked? jfriend00, I added the console log by removing the return statement from the async fn call and adding it directly after series(items.shift) in the fn declaration (not the first series call). I don't get why the console log started getting printed only after the second series call...why not after series(1)?

Comment: series(1) is calling series(2) and so on and they're all async but the code inside them isn't all async. So I am correct in assuming that every time the event loop refers back and runs the sync code in the call stack is one loop? The six series invocations will all occur independently from one another and the event loop will only move onto the next callback once the current running is finished? So in essence, it executes the callbacks in each phase synchronously before moving onto the next phase. But then again settimeout is in timers phase and the series cb is in poll phase most likely...